# Activate treeview again

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have two forms. The main form contains a `treeview`. After I show the second form, the treeview loses focus. That's okay, but I want to activate the treeview when the second form closes.

Form1.cs

```cs
namespace ex
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(this))
            {
                form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                form2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        internal void example()
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[1];
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode("aaaa");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            node = new TreeNode("bbbb");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            node = new TreeNode("cccc");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```cs
namespace ex
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1;

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.form1 = form1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            form1.example();

            //not working
            form1.treeView1.Focus();
            form1.treeView1.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form2 really shouldn't get so intimate with Form1.  Try turning your code around like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(this))
  {
    if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
      treeView1.Select();
      example();
    }
  }
}
```

If Form2 is supposed to supply any information to add to your TreeView control, you would set up a property on Form2 and access it from within this same code block.